# Simplify C# Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a better way to write this in vs2010 C#?

```
public bool IsAccept()
{
    //check the status is accept
    if (Status == null)
        return false;
    return Status.ToLower() == "accept";
}

public bool IsRefer()
{
    //check the status is refer
    if (Status == null)
        return false;
    return Status.ToLower() == "refer";
}


public bool IsAnyReviewState()
{
    if (IsAccept() || IsRefer())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Maybe a simplified way in C# 4 which I'm still learning.

Comment: not a real answer: just make it a ternary operator `public bool IsAccept() { return (Status == null) ? false : Status.ToLower() == "accept"; }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simpler version of your code (will work in all .NET versions down to 2.0) is the following:

```
public bool IsAccept
{
    get { return string.Equals("accept", Status, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); }
}

public bool IsRefer
{
    get { return string.Equals("refer", Status, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); }
}

public bool IsAnyReviewState
{
    get { return IsAccept || IsRefer; }
}
```

But a more appropriate solution would be to avoid string literals where an enumeration fits. If you receive the value from an external source, you should parse it into an enum as soon as possible, so that rest of the code deals with typed data only.

Answer (score 5):

### First wave

```
public bool IsAccept
{
    get { return Status != null && Status.ToLower() == "accept"; }
}

public bool IsRefer
{
    get { return Status != null && Status.ToLower() == "refer"; }
}

public bool IsAnyReviewState
{
    get { return IsAccept || IsRefer; }
}
```

### Second - enums

The Status property shold be an anum or a type code class. With an enum, you will have a simple solution you just have to watch for some problems when using it: 0 is universal enum value, (SomeEnum)564564 is valid, even if the enum only contain 1, 2; always have a default in a switch statement when using enums.

### Type code

Type code classes are sealed, they constructors are private and the available options are public static readonly fields. They are much like enums exept they can have other functions, like telling you IsReviewState() or you can easily localize them (you need a ResourceManager, a strongly typed resource file and for example a Display property to get the localized text).

Answer (score 0):

Gave this answer on SO, posting here since the question wasn't migrated.

```
public bool IsAnyReviewState()
{
    return new [] {"accept", "refer"}.Contains((Status??string.empty).ToString().ToLower())
}
```